# Restricting wildcard expansion to certain combinations in Snakemake

Tags: python, wildcard, snakemake

In my workflow, I wish to run some rules based on different wildcards. I have a **{group}** wildcard, which is derived from a directory, and a **{sample}** wildcard, which is derived from files inside that directory.

For example:

```
group1/
group1/sample1.fastq.gz
group1/sample2.fastq.gz


group2/
group2/sample3.fastq.gz
group2/sample4.fastq.gz
```

Here is how I currently take in these wildcards:

```
GROUP = [ dir for dir in os.listdir('directory/')
         if os.path.isdir(os.path.join('directory/', dir)) ]

SAMPLE = [os.path.basename(fn).replace("_M_1.fastq.gz", "")
            for fn in glob(f"directory/*/*_1.fastq.gz")]
```

I have some rules in my snakefile that operate only on the {group} wildcard, e.g.:

```
rule group_task:
    input:
        "directory/{group}"
    output:
        "other_directory/{group}/{group}_contig_file.fasta"
```

But other rules that would be better optimized if I could parallelize jobs from the {sample} wildcard for a given {group}, e.g.

```
rule sample_per_group_task:
    input:
        sample_reads = "directory/{group}/{sample}",
        group_contigs = "other_directory/{group}/{group}_contig_file.fasta"
    output:
        "other_directory/{group}/{group}{sample}.bam"
```

However, as expected, expansion of these wildcards would provide combinations that don't exist:

```
group1/sample3.fastq.gz
group1/sample4.fastq.gz

group2/sample1.fastq.gz
group2/sample2.fastq.gz
```

Therefore, my questions is: **Is it possible to constrain these wildcards such that combinations that don't exist do not get expanded?**

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Instead of constraining what are allowed combinations, I think there is the problem that your downstream rule(s) are expecting files as input that are not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside you may have bigger issues as Maarten points out in his comment and addressing your title and the main question in your post, your example where group 1 matches to `1` and `2` and group2 matches to `3` and `4` could use `zip` to get close to. `zip` use with expand is covered in the [expand function documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#the-expand-function). Look for, "by inserting a second positional argument this can be replaced by any combinatoric function, e.g. `zip`" in that section of the current documentation. However, I couldn't quite stumble on the clever combination to make it work so I fell back to Python. Keep in mind that Snakefile code is a superset of Python, and so you can use Python above your rules to get as granular as you want making a list to pass input. [A reply here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72879458/8508004) has a simple example of making a Python list and then passing it to an `input` in a rule. Related this are the [input functions](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/advanced.html#step-3-input-functions) Snakemake has. Those allow you to use wildcards to get the list of files more dynamically. They are added by Snakemake, but you can be more direct too if you want to use pure Python like I just suggested as the process to build the list of file names. I like the way it is summarized by Troy Comi [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72349141/8508004):

> "Remember snakemake is basically python with a little extra syntax. Any way you want to automate listing your requested ... files with python will work."

In your case, using Python's zip directly and using Python to make the combinations wanted could work something like this:

```py
import os
import sys

'''
GROUP = [ dir for dir in os.listdir('directory/')
         if os.path.isdir(os.path.join('directory/', dir)) ]

SAMPLE = [os.path.basename(fn).replace("_M_1.fastq.gz", "")
            for fn in glob(f"directory/*/*_1.fastq.gz")]
'''

# hardcode those for demo
GROUP = ["group1/","group2/"]
SAMPLE = [["sample1.fastq.gz","sample2.fastq.gz"],["sample3.fastq.gz","sample4.fastq.gz"]]

# SAMPLE should be a list of lists matching the order of groups. Your code for making `SAMPLE` will need to be changed to use GROUP to iterate and collect the files inside. You may want to use `fnmatch` instead of `glob`. Post in the comments if you are struggling with that.

grouped_by_elements_in_combo_wanted = list(zip(GROUP,SAMPLE))
combos_wanted = []
for having_combos in grouped_by_elements_in_combo_wanted:
    directory = having_combos[0]
    files_list = having_combos[1]
    for file in files_list:
        combos_wanted.append(directory+file)


rule sample_per_group_task:
    input: combos_wanted
```

That gives:

```bash
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in rule sample_per_group_task  in line 29 of /home/jovyan/Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule sample_per_group_task:
    affected files:
        group2/sample3.fastq.gz
        group1/sample2.fastq.gz
        group1/sample1.fastq.gz
        group2/sample4.fastq.gz
```

Note that you have to take out the demo hardcoding I did and change up the way you collect `SAMPLE`. `SAMPLE` is to be a list of lists with each list corresponding to the file names in that particular group in the same order it is in GROUP. I put comments in the code suggesting how that could be implemented.

I'm sure there is some more clever way to do this with wildcards using something itertools has like the Snakemake documentation uses itetools `zip` with expand but knowing some Python it was more direct for me to do it with Python.